# How to configure model class for nested JSON response with Alamofire and Decodable in iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, decodable

I'm using Alamofire and Decodable for a Google Books API request for performing a search.
I've created a Decodable model which I will add below and it worked up until I try to get any other field below "title" in "volumeInfo" (I've been commenting out properties one by one to check where it fails). The error I get after uncommenting "authors", "publisher" or anything other than "title" inside "volumeInfo" is:

```
responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "publisher", intValue: nil)
```

An example response is:

```
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "Ett09eLWE5oC",
   "etag": "WIwTdsmpnhs",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/Ett09eLWE5oC",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "The Picture of Dorian Gray",
    "authors": [
     "Oscar Wilde"
    ],
    "publisher": "Wordsworth Editions",
    "publishedDate": "1992",
    "description": "The handsome appearance of dissolute young Dorian Gray remains unchanged while the features in his portrait become distorted as his degeneration progresses",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "ISBN_10",
      "identifier": "1853260150"
     },
     {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9781853260155"
     }
    ],
    "readingModes": {
     "text": false,
     "image": true
    },
    "pageCount": 312,
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "categories": [
     "Fiction"
    ],
    "averageRating": 4.0,
    "ratingsCount": 6,
    "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
    "allowAnonLogging": false,
    "contentVersion": "1.1.2.0.preview.1",
    "panelizationSummary": {
     "containsEpubBubbles": false,
     "containsImageBubbles": false
    },
    "imageLinks": {
     "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Ett09eLWE5oC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
     "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Ett09eLWE5oC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
    },
    "language": "en",
    "previewLink": "http://books.google.ro/books?id=Ett09eLWE5oC&pg=PA130&dq=9781853260155&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
    "infoLink": "http://books.google.ro/books?id=Ett09eLWE5oC&dq=9781853260155&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Picture_of_Dorian_Gray.html?hl=&id=Ett09eLWE5oC"
   }
  }
```

My model:

```
struct Response: Decodable {

    struct VolumeInfo: Decodable {
        var title: String
        //var authors: [String]
        var publisher: String
        //var identifiers: [Identifier]
       //var image: ImageLink

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case title
            //case authors
            case publisher
            //case identifiers = "industryIdentifiers"
            //case image = "imageLinks"
        }
    }

    struct Identifier: Decodable {
        var type: String
        var identifier: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case type
            case identifier
        }
    }

    struct ImageLink: Decodable {
        var url: URL

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case url = "thumbnail"
        }
    }

    var id: String
    var volumeInfo: VolumeInfo
}
```

Comment: Decoding your json in a playground using JSONDecoder works perfectly fine, I also uncommented and tried with all the properties and this worked fine as well. Could some properties be optional perhaps and missing in some responses? Rather than commenting out properties make them optional

Comment: You were right! It works now! Thank you so much!